# OpenVPN won't start on boot (OSMC)

Tags: vpn, osmc

Just got my Pi 1 setup with OSMC yesterday. I've tried getting OpenVPN to start on boot, but no luck. In `etc/default/openvpn` here's my settings (Netherlands being Netherlands.ovpn):

```
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="none"
#AUTOSTART="home office"
AUTOSTART="Netherlands"
```

The only way I've been able to start the service OK is with:

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Netherlands.ovpn
```

Even using `sudo service openvpn start` doesn't work (thought it would).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like changing all the ".ovpn" files instead to use ".conf" extension worked. Not sure why that is. E.g.:

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Netherlands.conf
```