# openvpn client setup

Tags: raspbian, networking, vpn

I'm trying to setup openvpn as a client with private internet access 
running on the latest raspbian (18-March- 2016)

The openvpn setup I used does not run properly on bootup.

Here are the commands I have been using

```
sudo apt-get update   # this is to ensure that all the latest update on packages available an package upgrades
sudo apt-get upgrade  # This line will upgrade all the packages installed on your Raspberry Pi
sudo apt-get install openvpn

sudo wget https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/openvpn/openvpn.zip

sudo apt-get install unzip

unzip openvpn.zip -d openvpn

sudo cp openvpn/ca.crt openvpn/crl.pem /etc/openvpn/

sudo cp openvpn/CA*Toronto.ovpn /etc/openvpn/Toronto.conf

sudo nano /etc/openvpn/pass.txt   # inserted myuserid and password

sudo chmod 600 /etc/openvpn/pass.txt

sudo nano /etc/openvpn/Toronto.conf   

# change to ca line, auth-user-pass line, crl-pem to match the lines
#     ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
#     auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/pass.txt
#     crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem

sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Toronto.conf

sudo systemctl enable openvpn@Toronto

sudo reboot
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: How do you notice it doesn't work? What kind of debugging have you done so far? What did you find?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenVPN won't start on boot (OSMC)](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40216/openvpn-wont-start-on-boot-osmc)

Comment: mega.nz never expires links so i copied and pasted the first link and put in in text file. https://mega.nz/#!90EBgaBL!5VWyDW7b_xCMvvQGsR11_XzvePLK4kBA9UiYxZ-dSis